# minecraft user detection with php and javascript

Tags: php, javascript, html, css

I have a simple question that I just cannot find on google, is there any way, either php or javascript to grab the usernames of players on a minecraft server, or would a plugin be required. All I have been able to do is get the status of the server (online/offline)

Comment: Have you seen [this](https://gist.github.com/skakri/2134554)?

Answer (score 0):

I remember I had to use a plugin to get the players who were online. Hold on while I find my code for this.
EDIT: My teamviewer is down for some reason. I think i used this plugin: http://dev.bukkit.org/server-mods/simple-player-list/

Hopefully you can get it set up when using the examples provided.

Comment: While you are searching, this should only be a comment not an answer :-)